Method of manufactured solution for discontinues material properties
I am trying to verify a 1D unsteady heat equation. I used Finite volume method. My domain has an interface and conductivity changes after the interface. I am trying to verify my code using Method of manufactured solution. Did some literature review but so far could not understand exactly how to deal with the discontinuities at the interface.
I proposed two different manufactured solution before and after interface as T1 and T2.
When I make my T1 and T2 equal to each other and the fluxes are equal to each other at the interface, my manufactured solution and FVM matches well. But, I want to make T1 is not equal to T2 while fluxes are equal at the interface. When I do that, manufactured solution and FVM does not match.
To me, it should not be hard to apply manufactured solution(MMS) to 1D heat equation with discontinuous material but so far I could not find how to get the source term and add to my temperature equation.
I would be so grateful if you have any idea and share it with me.
Thank you in advance, Best.
